# File already existing - repeated name

Tags: java, android, performance, file, io

i am creating a file and when i create that file, i check if it already exists. If it already exists, i want to create it with the same name, but with the (1) after it. I am able to do that and here is the code :

```
    File apkReceived = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"+receivedApkName + ".apk");
                        if(apkReceived.exists()){
                         apkReceived=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"+receivedApkName + "(1)"+".apk");
                        }
                        byte[] buffer = new byte [8192];
                        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(apkReceived);
```

then it would continue... (i am writing things on the file).

This works but the problem is that in this situation :

FileTest.apk

FileTest(1).apk

If I receive another Filetest, it will sub my FileTest(1), since it will create it again.
A solution for this would be to check if the file exists again, but then i would have to be doing that for ever.

My goal would be to create (1)  and then (2) , etc.
Does any one of you know how to do this ?

EDIT: Obviously i could use a cicle to check it. The problem is on how to get the (1) and then the (2) and don't get the (1)(2)

Comment: `but then i would have to be doing that for ever.` No. Just a simple while loop would do to check if those files exist.

Comment: wow. This was a really stupid question. I am even embarassed. I am sorry. I haven't sleept in 37 hours. I am extremely sorry.

Comment: In princible you can change the `if(apkReceived.exists()` to a `while(apkReceived.exists()`. And then use a `number variable so you can construnt (number) for (1).` All 6 answers are too complex.

Comment: The problem with that is that on the 2nd run of the cicle it would check if FileTest(1).apk already exists, which would be ok, but then it will create a FileTest(1)(2).apk . After Marcin told me about the cicle (i obviously "woke up") and did what you said, but then i will that filetest(1)(2)

Comment: Dont understand a word of this. There would not be any problem. But as you already checked an answer this post is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do Something like this**

```
 File apkReceived = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"+receivedApkName + ".apk");

                if(apkReceived.exists()){

                    int new_int_postfix;

                    //Below _MAX is max numbers of file eg. _MAX = 100 
                    for(int i = 1; i < _MAX; i++) {

                    apkReceived = = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"+receivedApkName +"("+ i +")"+".apk");
                        if(!apkReceived.exists()) {
                            String []name_without_pre = receivedApkName.split("\\(");
                            receivedApkName = name_without_pre[0];
                            new_int_postfix = i;
                            break;

                        }
                    }

                 apkReceived = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"+receivedApkName + "("+new_int_postfix+")"+".apk");
                }

                byte[] buffer = new byte [8192];

                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(apkReceived);
```

Comment: That would do :

FileTest.apk
FileTest(1).apk
FileTest(1)(2).apk

Comment: Yeah, the key was the receivedApkName... Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

To avoid reinventing the wheel I suggest using `Timestamp` it hardly ever will have collisions.

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
Timestamp tstamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
File apkReceived = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"+receivedApkName + tstamp + ".apk");
```

Answer (score 1):

Some pseudocode to get you started:

- Fetch a list of all files in the directory
- For the one you want to copy: check if you already have one or more copies
- If you already have "file_(n)"; use "file_(n+1)" as new filename.

Obviously: you should clarify your requirements on the "maximum" n you want to allow; and what to happen when n copies were created; and another is asked for.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String filename =Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"+receivedApkName + ".apk";
File f = new File(filename);
String extension = ".apk";
int g = 0;

while(f.exists()) {
  int i = f.lastIndexOf('.');
  if (i > 0) 
     { extension = fileName.substring(i+1); }

   f.renameTo(f.getPath() + "\" + (f.getName() + g) + "." + extension)    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only store that one type of file in your directory you can do:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

count the size and size + 1 for your next filename.

you can also separate each file with similiar filename on their own directory.

Comment: This would help me to create the (1), (2) instead of the (1)(2) , since i could substring the names of the existing files and that way i could do the (1) and then the (2)